# x264 options for colorprim

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I have a source with the following color characteristics (as determined by ffprobe using "ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams source") colormatrix=smpte170m:colorprim=reserved:transfer=reserved.

I would like to preserve this and so I encoded with ffmpeg with libx264 by specifying the following x264 specific options:

> > "-vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -b:v 2400k -preset medium -x264opts ref=3:keyint=90:colormatrix=smpte170m:colorprim=reserved:transfer=reserved -r 30000/1001"

But now I get an error =>

> > [libx264 @ 0x2234820] bad value for 'colorprim': 'reserved'
> >
> > Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

What should the ideal mapping here be to preserve the input color characteristics ?

Comment: Can you share the input? `reserved` indicates that the value isn't designated for any color space but reserved for future assignment.